# Corrupt files/images when uploaded to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, formidable

I already googled all the internet and I didn't find my issue yet.
I'm using multipart to upload to nodejs, but all my files are coming corrupted, I used many solutions of parsing and I can do it with formidable, but I want to learn how to parse by my own.
The binary code of the output file is exactly the same of the original[size and binary(I used hexdump -C int terminal to check)].

Here's a sample of the code:

```js
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(!((req.url === "/upload") && (req.method === "POST"))){
        home(res);
    }else{
        upload(req, res);
    }
}).listen(8888);

function home(res){
    res.end("<html><body><form action='/upload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data''><input name='file' type='file'/><input type='submit'></form></body></html>");
}

function upload(req, res){
   
    var data = "";
    req.setEncoding("binary");
    req.addListener("data", function(chunk){
        data = chunk.split("\r\n")[4];/*This was my last chance, but it also failed*/
    });
    req.addListener("end", function(){
        res.end();
        console.log(data);
        fs.writeFile("icone.ico", data, "binary", function(err){/*I also used fs.createWriteStream*/
            console.log("done");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a multipart request. This means it's not just the raw contents of the single file you're uploading, but a special format that allows for multiple parts where each part is a separate form field (in your case there is only 1 part -- the file form field). You should look into using a module that can parse `multipart/form-data` requests for you such as [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy), [`multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty), or [`formidable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

Comment: In this case I'm receiving just one part, it is a favicon.
What I want is parse the multipart and then save the file on the disk without using modules.

Comment: Good luck writing a parser.